# Is there a way to stop the showing the activity feed

Tags: permissions, custom-profile

Currently when  we open User record, you can see their activities on the Feed tab..We have helpdesk profile, where they don't even want their Peers to see the emails sent by their peers...

Since these e-mails contain information that we do not want exposed to others can we STOP these responses from being posted to our custom helpdesk Profiles where they are viewable by others?

Comment: Do you care if you see the feeds/ is it an option to consider not showing feeds at all?

Comment: Yes..that is also an option.Is it possible to not to show feeds at profile level?

Comment: I do not know if it is the best option, but as far as I see there is an option to hide the feed from all the users. you can go to setup--> apps --> subtab apps and edit this option:Profile (self), Profile(Others). I think this will disable feeds from all the users profile not specific to one profile